# Wordpress meta_query not working in two cases

Tags: php, wordpress

Within a larger array of args for a [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) call, I am trying to use these two meta_queries:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'space_avail_days',
        'value' => array('mon', 'tue', 'wed'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'space_settings_restricted',
        'value' => 'restricted',
        'compare' => '!='
    )
),
```

Neither are working (together or independently).

Here's an overview of the data in both:

The first is a simple meta field (`'space_avail_days'`) whose value is an array of day abbreviations ('mon', 'tue', 'wed', etc). I simply want to check if a submitted array of days is within the meta's array of days.

The second query's meta (`'space_settings_restricted'`) can either be null, empty, or 'restricted' and I'm trying to get any posts that are specifically NOT 'restricted' (so, any that are set to either null or an empty value)

Neither one produces any results (although I know the values are present and correct on the posts)

If anyone has any ideas, they are appreciated!

Comment: Hello, can you share the complete query parameters, not only the meta_query ? Also, on the meta_query array, you need to add the relation 'AND' or 'OR', check docs on https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: The only other query params are 'posts_per_page' => -1, and 'post_type'=>'space' (custom post type).

Comment: It doesn't work with 'relation' in place either, but it defaults to 'AND' so it's not strictly required, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'space_avail_days',
        'value' => array('mon', 'tue', 'wed'),
        'operator' => $_POST['space_avail_days'] ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'space_settings_restricted',
        'value' => 'restricted',
        'compare' => $_POST['space_settings_restricted'] ? '=' : '!=',
    )
),
```